# Tab separated string split in C#

Tags: c#

There are several stackoverflow question posted but none of them works for me.

I have a string say

```
   string str = "15.24\t7.28\t6.04\t5.0";
```

In App.Config, I define a key value

```
   <add key="delimiter" value="\t"/>
```

In the program, I have something like this

```
 string delimiter = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["delimiter"]; 
 string[] parsedValues = str.Split(delimiter.ToCharArray());
```

While debugging I find that delimiter gets changed to "\t" and so it doesn't split the string.

I have tried changing App.Config to

```
 <add key="delimiter" value=@"\t"/>
```

but this gives an error.

Even the following gives error.

```
 <add key="delimiter" value='\t' />
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try replacing \t with `&#09;` in your config file. In XML files the tab character is represented by `&#09;`.

Answer (score 4):

with

```
<add key="delimiter" value="&#x9;"/>
```

you can do as below

```
string delimiter = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["delimiter"]; 
string[] stringSeparators = new string[] {delimiter };
var result =str.Split(stringSeparators,StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

**Result :**

```
15.24 
7.28 
6.04 
5.0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] parsedValues = str.Split(delimiter);
```

This is what you want. You do not want to change the delmiiter into a character array.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What overload for `Split` takes a single `string` argument, I cant find it?

Comment: Yeup you are correct, it says it wants a character array, but you can give it a single character. eg... `var something = "15.24\t7.28\t6.04\t5.0";
            var somethingArray = something.Split('\t');

            Console.WriteLine(somethingArray[0]); //15.26
            Console.WriteLine(somethingArray[1]); // 7.28`

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue a while ago, i ended up using `Regex.Unescape` to solve the issue

Example:

```
 string delimiter = Regex.Unescape(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["delimiter"]); 
 string[] parsedValues = str.Split(delimiter.ToCharArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] parsedValues = str.Split(new[] { delimiter }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

This code will get what you want. If you pass delimiter.ToCharArray() to string.Split method, it will use '\' and 't' to split your str, it is not because of the escape characters.